# Integration Testing with Large Databases

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, testing, integration-testing

I have an existing application that I wanting to add some automated integration testing to.  This is a .Net/SQL Server application with all data access managed through stored procedures.  The stored procedures may or may not contain business logic.  It seems most efficient to build-out our test base is by adding a tests for bugs as they are reported and resolved.  So, each test will be dependent on a very specific set of data that may be spread across multiple tables in multiple databases.  If the databases were small, we could simply spin up a copy of the databases containing the test data for each test before it runs and delete the database after the test finishes.  However, in total these databases are too large to copy and store in their entirety for every.  The subset of data actually used by each test would be manageable.  In total there are 8 databases.  The smallest is 200 MB the largest is 10 GB with the other 6 falling in between.

Getting the right subset of seems key to this process.  I don’t have much experience with SSIS, but I’m pretty sure we could create a predefined package that packages up the subset of data needed for the test.  The problem with this approach is that our applications covers many different functional areas and it seems daunting to build packages that cover all the scenarios needed for any given test.

Another option that seems ideal (on the surface anyway) would be to create a logging framework that could record all the data used by a stored procedure (some of our stored procs have multiple select statements from multiple tables).  So when we’re ready to create the data for our test case, we could simply turn on logging and run the test logic against the full/complete set of databases.  Then take the log of the records accessed during the run across all the databases/tables and create the smaller test specific databases from the log.  This log could be actual data or it could be a series of select statements we then use to get the actual data.  Is this too tall of an order?

Any advice on how to approach this situation would be helpful.

Comment: How many databases and what is the average size?

Comment: In total there are 8 databases.  The smallest is 200 MB the largest is 10 GB with the other 6 falling in between.

Comment: That is for the subset or for all data?

Comment: That is for all the data.  On average, the substes are likely to be just a few MB for each DB, but that will depend on the test.